# Google Sheets: Split text into groups of four words: Place each group of four words into cells across the row, max 12 words / 3 columns

Tags: google-sheets, join, split, multiple-columns

Sample code here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q4qRgXSq6xXhddArPCoBIuOOupRvokUd0andADCNN0Q/edit?usp=sharing

In column D3:D I have text that varies between 0-13 words.

I want to place a code in Column C that will separate this text into groups of 4 words per cell across the row.

If there are zero words I want it to fail gracefully. If there are 12 or more words I want it to add "..." after the 12th word and cut off the string, not using any more columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Λ,if(Λ="",,let(Σ,split(reduce(Λ,{4,7,10},lambda(a,c,substitute(a," ","|",c))),"|"),
    iferror(hstack(index(Σ,,1),index(Σ,,2),let(Δ,index(Σ,,3),if(len(iferror(index(Σ,,4))),Δ&"...",Δ))))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possible solution:

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   LET(a,A2:A8,
       q,REGEXREPLACE(
           REGEXREPLACE(a,"((?:\w+ ){1,3}(?:\w+)?)|.","$1|"),
           "\|*$",),
       IF(a="",,SPLIT(q&IF(REGEXREPLACE(q,"\|+"," ")=a,,"..."),"|"))))
```

### Explanation

First we separate each group of max 4 words with a pipe

```cpp
REGEXREPLACE(a,"((?:\w+ ){1,3}(?:\w+)?)|.","$1|")
```

We remove the trailing pipes

```cpp
REGEXREPLACE(...,"\|*",)
```

We call this new string `q` and we check if this string with spaces instead of pipes is equal to the value in column A, if it is, we return `q`, otherwise we return `q&"..."`

```cpp
q&IF(REGEXREPLACE(q,"\|+"," ")=a,,"...")
```

Finally, we split by the pipe

```cpp
SPLIT(q&IF(REGEXREPLACE(q,"\|+"," ")=a,,"..."),"|")
```

## Alternative solution

```cpp
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   MAP(A2:A8,LAMBDA(a,
     LET(w,IFNA(WRAPROWS(SPLIT(a," "),4)),
         TOROW(TRIM(
           BYROW(w,LAMBDA(r,JOIN(" ",r)))&
           IF(ROWS(w)>3,IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(w)-1)=3,"...",),)),2)))))
```

Separate the words in groups of 4 using [`WRAPROWS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/13184285?hl=en)

```cpp
IFNA(WRAPROWS(SPLIT(a," "),4)) ← w
```

Concatenate them

```cpp
BYROW(w,LAMBDA(r,JOIN(" ",r)))
```

If there are more than 3 groups of words, i.e. if the words are > 12, add `"..."` to the end of the last row

```cpp
IF(ROWS(w)>3,IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(w)-1)=3,"...",),)
```

Trim the result and transpose it

```cpp
TOROW(TRIM(...),2)
```