# Google Sheets: Use a Conditional Function to separate a sentence in one cell into multiple parts in subsequent cells

Tags: google-sheets, lambda, split, row, regex-replace

I want to separate a one-cell sentence into cells of 4 words each in the same row.
If the sentence has more than 12 words, the 12th word should append "..." and add no more words. **SPECIAL CONDITION: I cannot have a cell with only one word in it.** If a sentence has five words, cell 1 should use three words, cell 2 should use two words.

[image]

Example data can be found here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q4qRgXSq6xXhddArPCoBIuOOupRvokUd0andADCNN0Q/edit#gid=0

> This is based on the question found here:
> [Google Sheets: Split text into groups of four words: Place each group of four words into cells across the row, max 12 words / 3 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78049557/google-sheets-split-text-into-groups-of-four-words-place-each-group-of-four-wo/78049768#78049768)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Improvising from the existing formula provided in the [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78049647/5479575):*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Λ,if(Λ="",,let(Σ,split(reduce(Λ,{4,7,10},lambda(a,c,substitute(a," ","|",c))),"|"),a,index(Σ,,1),b,index(Σ,,2),d,index(Σ,,3),c,if(len(iferror(index(Σ,,4))),d&"...",d),
      Δ,map({a,b,c},lambda(Ξ,counta(iferror(split(Ξ," "))))),x,index(Δ,,1),y,index(Δ,,2),z,index(Δ,,3),
      iferror(if(y=1,split(substitute(join(" ",{a,b})," ","|",3),"|"),if(z=1,hstack(a,split(substitute(join(" ",{b,c})," ","|",3),"|")),hstack(a,b,c))))))))
```

[image]

***UPDATED FORMULA***

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(x,if(x="",,let(Λ,split(x," "),Σ,counta(Λ),
     hstack(
            join(" ",choosecols(Λ,if(Σ=6,{1,2,3,4},if(Σ>4,{1,2,3,4,5},sequence(Σ))))),
            concat(join(" ",iferror(choosecols(Λ,if(Σ=6,{5,6},if(Σ<6,,if(Σ>9,{6,7,8,9,10},sequence(Σ-5,1,6))))))),if(Σ>10,"...",))
            )))))
```

`logic` : ***A simple if-conditional approach is used here depending on the total number of words available in the sentence. they are split first by blank space & then joined as phrases depending on the set rules of `2 Columns, 5 words per column, no column with 1 word`***

[image]

Comment: Two things: 1. I'm trying to modify this for a two column use-case, but I can't figure out how.  2. I'd like to make a donation to you if you accept those. Please feel free to give me a paypal, patreon, or other method if you have one!

Comment: `1` showcase the expected scenario in your test sheet `2`its cool:) not needed

Comment: Added the new expected result in Test Sheet: 2 Columns, 5 words per column, no column with 1 word. So appreciated - this is above my skill, but I learn from your approach. Test Sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q4qRgXSq6xXhddArPCoBIuOOupRvokUd0andADCNN0Q/edit#gid=0

Comment: Updated with a formula in the answer section. this one uses if-condition approach depending on the no. of words in the given sentence.

Comment: I understand it!  I used your code plus some study and wrote the following, which works for these conditions: 3 COLUMNS, 3 WORDS PER COLUMN, NO COLUMN WITH ONE WORD, PLUS "..." if 9+:   map(D60:D,lambda(x,if(x="",,let(Λ,split(x," "),Σ,counta(Λ),
     hstack(
               join(" ",choosecols(Λ,if(Σ=4,{1,2},if(Σ>3,{1,2,3},sequence(Σ))))),
       join(" ",iferror(choosecols(Λ, if(Σ=4,{3,4}, if(Σ=7,{4,5}, if(Σ>4,{4,5,6},sequence(Σ-3,1,4))))))),
concat(join(" ",iferror(choosecols(Λ, if(Σ=7,{6,7}, if(Σ=8,{7,8}, if(Σ>5, {7,8,9}, sequence(Σ-6,1,7))))))),if(Σ>9,"...",))
            )))))

Comment: A slight correction for anyone who might be looking: map(D3:D,lambda(x,if(x="",,let(Λ,split(x," "),Σ,counta(Λ),
     hstack(
               join(" ",choosecols(Λ,if(Σ=4,{1,2},if(Σ>3,{1,2,3},sequence(Σ))))),
       join(" ",iferror(choosecols(Λ, if(Σ=4,{3,4}, if(Σ=7,{4,5}, if(Σ>5,{4,5,6},sequence(Σ-3,1,4))))))),
concat(join(" ",iferror(choosecols(Λ, if(Σ=7,{6,7}, if(Σ=8,{7,8}, if(Σ>8, {7,8,9}, sequence(Σ-6,1,7))))))),if(Σ>9,"...",))
            )))))

Comment: either this `if(Σ=8,{7,8}` OR  `sequence(Σ-6,1,7)`can be removed?!

Comment: I think I added the sigma = 8 as a hack because 8 words wasn't working. The reason was that I had coded  Σ>6, {7,8,9} as I was trying to understand it. Looking at your code, I later realized  >6 should be >8. Then I didn't change the other parts. I'm still learning. I really appreciate the guidance!